# Calculate Difference Betweet 2 Timestamps CORRECTLY

Tags: php, database, oop, real-time, game-engine

I'm Trying to make a Real-Time Handled BrowserGame but I can't get the system to calculate the difference between 2 Timestamps to work, If the result is below the needed time to perform something it returns negative...

Like when offline, adding Resources.., The system uses a function that stores the Login Time and Logout Time and next time the User Logs in, It calculates the Time Difference and Calculate how much Resources the User gets..

But the Resources return Negative.. (EG: -1186, -54868, ETC)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: post some code for actual help

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
  $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Taken straight from the DateTime class. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Thanks, but.., Is it possible to calculate in seconds????

Answer (score 1):

If the time difference is negative, the first thing I think it could be would be that you have the arguments to your difference-finding function backwards.

Comment: I don't really see a problem.., ill send u the code snippet asap.., i'm not on my PC

My code works fine if the difference in hours is over 1... :/